# Is it possible to format a hard drive with greater than 64kb clusters?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, filesystems

If I know the "exact" size of every file I'm putting on the disk, to the nearest 1 MB, is it possible for me to choose a cluster size greater than 64 KB to speed up reads/writes?

Is this a possible limitation of the file system, operating system, or physical drive?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply give it a try and report back here?

Comment: @arkascha is there a way to do it, though? I can't seem to find one...I'd really love to try it out.

Comment: Ah, so your real question is: "how can I change the cluster size of a hard drive?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just not with NTFS.

Selecting an exFAT partition allows for clusters in the megabytes.